# Changing rows using filters of form

Tags: ms-access

I want to change the Group By column that are selected in a form
So that it can be updated dynamically in the SQL query of the table

Supposed columns are orders_id, customers, year,location
I want the count of orders based on the options selected in a combo box in a form of year, location etc

```
SELECT Count(ORDER_ID) as orders, [Forms]![SELECTION TAB]![Combo13]FROM [Closed orders] GROUP BY [Closed orders].[Forms]![SELECTION TAB]![Combo13]
```

As I'm selecting the options for column names it should work in the query, correct me if there is anything wrong.
It's not getting effected dynamically when i'm using the query in a sbform of main form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after, but an aggregating query is in any case read-only.

Also, your SQL seems flaky. Maybe it should read:

```
SELECT Count(ORDER_ID) as orders, [Forms]![SELECTION TAB]![Combo13] 
FROM [Closed orders] 
WHERE [SomeFieldOfTable] = [Forms]![SELECTION TAB]![Combo13] 
GROUP BY [SomeOtherFieldOfTable]
```

Just guessing.

Comment: I want the "[Forms]![SELECTION TAB]![Combo13]" in the aggregate query based on the values i select in the drop down box from Form.
I think the WHERE is not required as I don't require any condition, I only want to get the result with different column based on the value i select in a drop down box and it needs to be applied to the query in an other query outside of the form.
So here I used the After_update() event procedure to link the Combox value to the query. Thanks for the Suggestion !!!